# Replacing method in class doesn't update within parent class usage types

Tags: typescript

I am trying to make changes to the `alpha` method within `Cat` and have `beta` reflect those changes.

```
const wrapperFn = <T extends (...args: any) => any> (a: T) => { 
    return (...args: Parameters<T>) => {
        return ''
    }
}

class FourLegged { 
    alpha = ({ foo }: { foo: string }) => foo
    beta = wrapperFn(this.alpha)
}

class Cat extends FourLegged {
    alpha = ({ foo, bar }: { foo: string, bar?: number}) => (foo + bar)
}

const c = new Cat()

c.beta({ foo: 'foo', bar: 3 })
```

`bar: 3` has an error

> Argument of type '{ foo: string; bar: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ foo: string; }'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'bar' does not exist in type '{ foo: string; }'.(2345)

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=5#code/MYewdgzgLgBA7gJwIYAcUFMEDEwwLwwA8AKjOgB5TpgAmEMAFAHQtIIDmEAXDEmAJ4BKfAD5eAsQyQ9iwvGIDeMALAAoGBpgJ0UAK4JczVh24wACmyQBbHZggkRcxWs2utO-bgDkXl5oC+aoGqasAANkgQ9Fgg+gAy6Ozs6DQwSn4aSGEoABZI+IxKAGYgIDD+PMWlPNAIAJZg7OVOMCUgGTAARjr5BIioGNhgDFA5dRBMWblIgkFqoRFRMADCSLAUVLTRsQgJSSlpHVN5BQxVIAA0XWzlla3VMLUN7FedbAD8PGC6Vt0IzaJGG0YABqa4IWaqYKhcDQGDAApgdBwFZrBiQ0JMbpQJBne4gHheNpeV5sHgAZmaQA)

Is there some way to update this `beta` without copying it over? Perhaps a decorator?

Here's one possible idea:

```
const wrapperFn = <T extends (...args: any) => any> (a: T) => { 
    return (...args: Parameters<T>) => {
        return ''
    }
}

const example = (value: typeof replacements) => class FourLegged { 
    replace = value()
    alpha = ({ foo }: { foo: string }) => foo
    beta = wrapperFn(this.replace.alpha || this.alpha)
}

const replacements = () => { 
    const alpha = ({ foo, bar }: { foo: string, bar?: number }) => (foo + bar)
    return { alpha }
    // return { alpha: null }
}
class Cat extends example(replacements) { }

const c = new Cat()

c.beta({ foo: 'foo', bar: 1 })
```

Idea 2:

```
abstract class FourLegged <replaceAlpha extends (...args: any) => any> { 
    replaceAlpha: replaceAlpha | null = null
    alpha = ({ foo }: { foo: string }) => foo
    beta = wrapperFn(this.replaceAlpha || this.alpha)
}

class Cat extends FourLegged<Cat['replaceAlpha']> {
    replaceAlpha = ({ foo, bar }: { foo: string, bar?: number }) => (foo + bar)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The type of subclass-relative typing you're looking for should be possible with a [polymorphic `this` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types):

```
class FourLegged {
    alpha = ({ foo }: { foo: string }) => foo
    beta = wrapperFn<this["alpha"]>(this.alpha)
}
```

Here we've explicitly specified the type parameter in `wapperFunction` as `this["alpha"]` instead of allowing the compiler to infer it as `(x: {foo: string}) => string`.  The difference is that `this["alpha"]` means "whatever the type of the `alpha` method is on the subclass you're looking at".

Then the following should work for you as you expect:

```
class Cat extends FourLegged {
    alpha = ({ foo, bar }: { foo: string, bar?: number }) => (foo + bar)
}
const c = new Cat()
c.beta({ foo: 'foo', bar: 3 }) // no error
```

Note that polymorphic `this` types are easier to *use* but harder to *implement*.  If you try to do something with `this.beta()` inside of your `FourLegged` or `Cat` implementations, you will likely get a compiler error.  So beware.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBA7gJwIYAcUFMEDEwwLwwA8AKjOgB5TpgAmEMAFAHQtIIDmEAXDEmAJ4BKfAD5eAkQyQ9iwvGIDeAKBiqYCdFACuCXM1YduMAApskAW02YIJEXMUwVa5xu26YAcg9PVAXyX+SsAANkgQ9FggOgAy6Ozs6DQwys5IwSgAFkj4jAowAGYgIDC+PHmFIDzQCACWYOwl9gVFPjAARprZBIioGNhghFAZNRAA2gBEaZlI4wC6kkMjTFNZggFKQaHhMADCSLAUVLQRUQix8YnJrStduc0gADTtbCVl91VQtfVPbWwA-DwwFpzB0EI1RIwKjAANTPBBrQKgSCwYA5MDoOC7fYMNZBJgdKBIBjlIo8DwVDw-Ng8ADMjSAA)

Comment: This does take care of making sure the typing works, but as [pointed out here](https://gitter.im/Microsoft/TypeScript?at=5dd1ba1ae75b2d5a19eeb831). Because `beta` is assigned in the constructor it never changes the function when alpha is added in `Cat`. So `beta` is still using the original `this.alpha`.